# Is there any way to convert my wordpress website to wix?

Tags: wordpress, web, velo

Today I'm very concerned about one thing. Can anyone tell me that can I convert my WordPress website to wix website. Please help me with your helpful suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware [Wix will only automatically import blog posts from WordPress](https://support.wix.com/en/article/importing-blog-posts-from-wordpress-to-the-new-wix-blog) - I think you'll have to manually import the rest of your content into Wix from your WordPress website.

Of course, this does beg the question of "why would a store for WordPress themes and plugins not use WordPress?"...